# Unity, Vr, Vive - Controllers To Play / Pause a Video?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I am new and currently trying to get my Vive Controllers to Pause / Play Unity. So far i Can see my "hands" and it does Recognise my triggers, which is all it needs to.

Does Anyone know how to make it Pause when I press the Trigger and then Start when I press it again ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class Viveinput : MonoBehaviour
{
[SteamVR_DefaultAction("Squeeze")]
public SteamVR_Action_Single squeezeAction;
public bool paused;

void Update () {
    if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.GrabPinch.GetLastStateUp(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any))
    {
        print(" Grab Pinch Up");
    }
    float triggerValue = squeezeAction.GetAxis(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any);

    if (triggerValue > 00f)
    {
        print(triggerValue);
    }

}
}
```

This is What I am using atm for connection between controller and Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your video is playing on a `VideoPlayer` MonoBehaviour :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class Viveinput : MonoBehaviour
{
public VideoPlayer video;

[SteamVR_DefaultAction("Squeeze")]
public SteamVR_Action_Single squeezeAction;
private bool _triggered = false;

void Update () {
    if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.GrabPinch.GetLastStateUp(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any))
    {
        print(" Grab Pinch Up");
    }
    float triggerValue = squeezeAction.GetAxis(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any);

    if (triggerValue > 0f && !_triggered)
    {
        _triggered = true; // This will prevent the following code to be executed each frames when pressing the trigger.
        if(!video.isPlaying) { // You dont need a paused boolean as the videoplayer has a property for that.
            video.Play();
        } else {
            video.Pause();
        }
    } else {
         _triggered = false;
    }    
}
}
```

You need to drag and drop the VideoPlayer in the editor and it should be it.

Comment: I am currently just watching the video in Unity itself. And so using the Play and Pause in unity right now.

Comment: Ha, you want to Pause or Play the Unity Player, so you can start the playmode from your controllers ?

Comment: It is not really clear in the title or in your question :)

Comment: Yes :) I am very new to this. I have made a Inverted Sphere with the Camera in it. And what I am trying to do is Pause it while it's running and then Starting it again. Not sure if it's the best way to do it  :)

Comment: Then you have a videoplayer reading the video playing on your inverted sphere right ? 
If yes the code I shared is right for you :)

Comment: Right now I am just using the play button in Unity to start the stuff I made and stop it. Would VLC Work ?

Comment: You cannot start the PlayMode from script unfortunatly. But if I understand, you want to play a 360 video on a inverted sphere. Then you should have a ``VideoPlayer`` Component attached to that sphere.

Comment: Yeah, I have a video clip attached. But It gives me Red lines under video in the code you provided.

Comment: Hav you added this line? ``public VideoPlayer video;``

Comment: I forgot that line. :) also needed the     Using UnityEngine.Video;

Comment: No problems ! Welcome to SO 1